# react-native-image-resizer issue. 'React/RCTImageURLLoader.h' file not found

Tags: react-native

I'm using react-native-image-resizer.
RN - 0.59

I don't want to upgrade RN.

When I installed this library and ran, it said  'React/RCTImageURLLoader.h' file not found.

How can I solve this?

Thanks,

Comment: Did you try to delete node modules and try to "npm install" again

Comment: try this https://github.com/bamlab/react-native-image-resizer/issues/204

Comment: @EmilMammadov I did it but it's not working

Answer (score 0):

If you're not willing to upgrade your RN version,
downgrade to

> react-native-image-resizer 1.0.1

and run pod install again, this will fix your problem.
I did same to fix this issue.

Answer (score -1):

Upgrade your React Native and also do a pod install. This should fix your problem

Comment: I said I don't want to upgrade RN

Answer (score -1):

Try to use an older version of `react-native-image-resizer` by typing:

```
yarn add react-native-image-resizer@next
```

then select the `V1.0.0`

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can try to manual link missing files?

https://reactnative.dev/docs/linking-libraries-ios